# Proof verification meromorphic functions on $\tilde{\mathbb{C}}$ are quotients of polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on the Riemann-sphere $\tilde{\mathbb{C}}$ and assume $f$ is meromorphic. I want to prove that $f$ is the quotient of two polynomials.

Since the Riemann-sphere is compact, the set of poles of $f$ forms a finite set $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ with $d_i$ the order of $a_i$. Then I know the function $g(z)=f(z)(z-a_1)^{d_1}(z-a_2)^{d_2}…(z-a_n)^{d_n}$ is holomorphic. How can I show that $g$ is a quotient of polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about how you deal with $\infty$ as a pole!

After clearing the finite and $\infty$ poles, use:

> A holomorphic function $f\colon\tilde{\mathbb C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is necessarily constant.

---

**Edit**: Note that multiplying by $(z-a)$ remove a pole $a$ at the cost of introducing $\infty$ as a pole.  One way to clear all (finite and infinite) poles is to subtract off the principal parts.  Alternatively, you can cancel the zeros and poles together by considering
\begin{align*}
g(z)&=f(z)\prod_{i=1}^nM(z;z_i,p_i)\\
M(z;z_i,p_i) &=\begin{cases}
\frac{z-p_i}{z-z_i} & z_i,p_i\neq\infty\\
z-p_i & z_i=\infty\\
\frac1{z-z_i} & p_i=\infty
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $p_1,\dots,p_n$ are the poles of $f$ (appearing with multiplicities) and $z_1,\dots,z_n$ are the zeros of $f$ (again, with multiplicities).

Comment: Does that follow from Liousville? Why wouild it be constant?

Comment: Recall: continuous image of compact is compact, and the open mapping theorem tells you $f(\tilde{\mathbb C})$ is open if $f$ is not constant.  But there are no nonempty open compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you :) How would I deal with the case that $\infty$ is a pole?

Comment: One way is to use the zeros to help you.

Comment: The zeros of $1/g$?

Comment: Not really.  See edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94385/discussion-between-johnduck-and-user10354138).